# Best practice for a Listview with variable and fixed items

Tags: flutter, dart

For a listView with variable elements, followed by fixed ones, which is the best pattern in flutter?

The simpler example is having the variable items on the top (which is my current case), but having them elsewhere (bottom, mixed, etc) could be even worse with this pattern:

```dart
class SomeViewState extends State<SomeView> {

final List<String> varItems = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
//final List<String> varItems = [];

List<Widget> getFixedItems() {
  return [
    ListTile(),
    ListTile(),
    Divider(),
    SwitchListTile(),
    ...];
}
Widget build(){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: varItems.lenght + getFixedItems().lenght,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      if( index < (varItems.length-1) ){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(varItems[index]),
        );
      } else {
        return getFixedItems()[index - varItems.length];
      }
    },
```

I can optimize it by assigning the list to the `initState` and then managing a single list of items via `setState`- but the underlying idea is still the same, which doesn't sound very good. I can't stop thinking this would have been solved better by having two list views sharing the same vertical space, but that is not possible with the layout manager flutter provides.

Comment: 'I can't stop thinking this would have been solved better by having two list views sharing the same vertical space, but that is not possible with the layout manager flutter provides." yes, it is, use `CustomScrollView` with two `SliverList` as `slivers` property

Answer (score 0):

Another option based on nesting listviews which I will leave here to be accepted if that is the best possible trade-off.

```dart
Widget build() {
return ListView(
  children: [
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: false,
      ... build from your varItems ...
    ),
    ListView(
      children: [
        ... your fixed elements ...
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
}
```

Easy to mix and match fixed and variable elements, if you know the variable element position region beforehand.

... but still came sort of a way to fiddle with the Widget state in a safe way. For example, inserting items as they came in specific positions.

Comment: using `shrinkWrap: true` in `ListView.builder` is pointless as it builds all the items at once, instead use `CustomScrollView` with two `SliverList`s

Comment: also it simply throws exception (Vertical viewport was given unbounded heigh) when scrolling down the list

Comment: @pskink I see what you mean. I had missed on the sliverList. So it is just the listing part of the listView, inside the customScroller which is just the scrolling part. Makes perfect sense! (i don't get the exception tho. testing on web and android)